# Send and Receive data C# using network stream

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

Hi I am trying to send a string from a client to a server. It does not work so I am trying to test the functions below by sending data and receiving data on the same machine.

The problem that I encounted was that `_serverStream.DataAvailable` in `ReceiveData()` always returns false. How do I check that both functions are working correctly? Is the `_serverStream` unable to send/receive data?

```
    public void SendData(string dataToSend)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataToSend))
            return;

        _serverStream = _serverClient.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSend);
            _serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            //_serverStream.Flush();
    }

    public string ReceiveData()
    {

        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        _serverStream = _serverClient.GetStream();
        _serverStream.ReadTimeout = 100;
        while (true)
        {

            if (_serverStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                int read = _serverStream.ReadByte();
                if (read > 0)
                {
                    message.Append((char)read);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (message.ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return message.ToString();
    }
```

I call the `SendData()` and `ReceiveData()` as below:

```
    tcpclient.SendData(username);
    string test = tcpclient.ReceiveData();
    MessageBox.Show(test);
```

Comment: Your usage of DataAvailable is a bug. Almost all usages of DataAvailable are wrong. Search for DataAvailable to see why.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not shown in your code, I'm guessing `_serverClient` is a TcpClient.

In both methods, you get a network stream from the same `_serverClient`, so you're accessing the *exact same* network stream. And it seems you expect that when you write data to the network stream in `SendData`, you should be able to read that same data within `ReceiveData`, which is not correct.

When you write data to a network stream, it is actually **sent** over the network -- it is not available to be read from the same network stream. You can only read data that you *receive* from the remote endpoint. In other words, unless you have a remote endpoint sending you back data, you won't have any `DataAvailable` to read.

In `ReceiveData`, you should be getting the network stream from the server end, e.g. from a `TcpClient` which was returned by calling `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient`, not from the same `TcpClient` that you used to send data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I realised I am using the same network stream so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Eren:   If we want to read and then to write, do we need to create two network streams?

Comment: No, you don't need to. You can read and write on a single network stream. However, when you write, you won't be able to read those bytes from the same network steam. You can only read the bytes that were sent from the remote side. It's like a telephone, you can talk and listen at the same time, but you only listen to what the other party said. You don't say something and except to hear your own words back.